# how to create token based login mechanism in iOS app using Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, token

I want to create a token based login authentication in iOS application using Swift 3. I get the user_email and password from API and Authenticate whether credentials are correct or not if user is valid then I need to create a token and save the token for the next preferences. I don't have idea how to do this with the token. Please suggest me how to do this in my iOS application.

Comment: Does your API return an auth token?

Comment: Check out an OAuth2 tutorial like this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: Firebase has good authentication mechanisms or if you're coding an API then JSON Web Tokens could help you. Good luck.

Comment: @StevenOjo yes API(RestFul) returns an auth token